# KendoUI Grid Custom Popup template for create button

Tags: php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have installed KendoGrid with POPUP option.

Now i am stuck someplace and i cant find any help to fix it with the way i want..

So here is problem that i am facing with KendoGrid popup editing.

When i click ADD New Record, the header on Top shows Edit, same as it shows on when i click on Edit.

http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/BCBzS/1/

also the button shows Update, instead it should be save button on create popup window..

i think i have to add something more like this below for creating new record..

```
editable: {
    mode: "popup",
    template: kendo.template($("#popup_editor").html())
},
```

and have the popup create template different from edit template?

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [demo page](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-popup.html) for popup editing this seems to be the normal behaviour...

But you can trick and use the `edit` event of the grid in order to change that. Just add at the beginning of this event the following code :

```
if(!e.model.Id) {
    $(".k-window .k-window-title").text("Add new record");
    $(".k-window .k-grid-update").html("<span class=\"k-icon k-update\"></span>Create");
}
```

See the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BCBzS/265/).

Comment: Problem Solved with your Trick.. JsFiddle you Updated Helped me alot.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kendo UI grid localization for changing the popup titles.

For changing the `Edit` title you should define in the grid:

```
editable  : {
    mode : "popup",
    window : {
        title: "Create",
    }
},
```

For changing the label of the buttons we need to do a little trick... Those labels can be localized in `column.command` as follow:

```
columns   : [
    {
        command: [
            {
                name: "edit",
                text: { edit: "Modify", update: "Save", cancel: "Cancel"}
            }
        ],
    },
    ...
```

The problem is that both window title and button labels are shared between edit and create buttons so changing one you change both. Can you find some labels that work for both?

See it running in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/BCBzS/267/)

Comment: Sir, with your way isnt there is any option to have both edit popup window and create popup window have different title names?

Comment: Sir, Problem Solved. Solution Given by @Samuel Caillerie.

Comment: There is but it is a lot of work... You define a _custom_ toolbar command that when clicked opens a window, in addition to the form, you add the two buttons (save and cancel), you intercept the click on those buttons and do any needed operation. As I said... lot of work but you are the one if it is really needed.

Comment: oh. Wished i had time for it.
For Now need to save some time for my self.
Many Thanks for Help thou..

Answer (score 0):

Do this by adding Following Code

```
                           edit: function (e) { if (!e.model.isNew()) {
                                e.container.kendoWindow("title", "Update Address");
                            } else {
                                e.container.kendoWindow("title", "New Address");
                            }
                        }
```